# Why regex is giving me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inputString = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  var result = inputString.match(/http:\/\/(?:.*\.|.*)imdb.com\/(?:t|T)itle(?:\?|\/)(..\d+)/i);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result[1];
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <p>Enter the URL:</p><input id="ur" type="text" name="url">
  <button type="submit" class="button secondary" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction();" value="Load">Load</button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Result is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

I am not sure where I am making mistake in my function.

I am expecting to get

```
tt8760708
```

from

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8760708
```

Comment: Your pattern does not match as you are matching `http://` and not `https://`, see https://regex101.com/r/PPRdfd/1 In the code, you can first check if you have a match, then take the group 1 value.

Comment: Oh, man, thanks a lot!
Can you please tell me how to implement this regex https://regex101.com/r/uO6fZ6/1
How to put it in var result = inputString.match();

Comment: That regex101 link has different example strings, are those all the matches that you want?

Comment: Yes, I want to match as many possible paterns, that regex looks good, but I am not sure how to implement it.
I don't know to code with regex honestly, I just use what I find on internet.

Comment: Also mobile imdb links if possible.

Comment: You could use a mechanism like this https://jsfiddle.net/tr89uq5j/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is a problem with your regexp.

Second the string might not match the regexp so there will be no array elements! Therefore `result` would be `[]`.

There is your error when trying to call `result[1]`.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')

If you use an alternative if array was empty your issues would solve:

```js
result? result[1]: ''
```

Change your function to this:

```js
function myFunction(){   
  var inputString = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  var result = inputString.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|m\.)?(?:imdb.com\/title\/)?(tt[0-9]+)/i);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result? result[1]: '';
}
```

There is snippet of the answer:

```js
function myFunction(){   
  var inputString = document.getElementById("ur").value;
  var result = inputString.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.|m\.)?(?:imdb.com\/title\/)?(tt[0-9]+)/i);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result? result[1]: '';
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false">
  <p>Enter the URL:</p><input id="ur" type="text" name="url">
  <button type="submit" class="button secondary" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction();" value="Load">Load</button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement this regex https://regex101.com/r/uO6fZ6/1 How to put it in var result = inputString.match();

Comment: You want to match multiple at the same time? Or you want to match any thing else?

Comment: I just want to change existing one with this one, as it matches better with both http, https and other paterns.

Comment: changed the answer test and accept as answer if it was helpful

Comment: Yeah, that's great, thanks.
Is it possible to include https://m.imdb.com/ in same regex?

Comment: You updated the pattern, but if there is another string that does not match, the OP ends up with the same problem.

Comment: Everything fixed for you, try again.

Comment: Can you add an answer to the question? The question is _"Why regex is giving me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')?"_